# How to retrieve messages from RabbitMQ DeadLetter queue using MassTransit?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm trying to notify the user when a message is not received after some time, using **MassTransit** and **RabbitMQ**.

From what I read, the timeout is set using the **TimeToLive** property when the message is published. When that specified time runs out, the message should be automatically added to a **Dead Letter** queue, named with a "_skipped" at the end.

How do I retrieve messages from Dead Letter queues? In my attempt below, the message is added to the both queues right away, and it never times out.

I think I could do this using sagas, but it seems like a over complicated solution for such a simple problem, so I would like to avoid using it if at all possible.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bus = CreateBus("rabbitmq://localhost/", "guest", "guest", true);

    var msg = new TestMessage("First Message");
    LogMessageSent(msg);
    bus.Publish(msg, c => c.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

    Console.ReadKey();

    bus.Stop();

    bus = CreateBus("rabbitmq://localhost/", "guest", "guest", false);

    msg = new TestMessage("SecondMessage");
    LogMessageSent(msg);
    bus.Publish(msg, c => c.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

    Console.ReadKey();

    bus.Stop();
}

private static IBusControl CreateBus(string rabbitUrl, string username, string password, bool enableEndpoint)
{
    var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(c =>
    {
        var host = c.Host(new Uri(rabbitUrl), h =>
        {
            h.Username(username);
            h.Password(password);
        });

        if (enableEndpoint)
        {
            c.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestQueue", x =>
            {
                x.Handler<TestMessage>(e => LogMessageReceived(e.Message, "TestQueue"));
            });
        }

        c.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestQueue_skipped", x =>
        {
            x.Handler<TestMessage>(e => LogMessageReceived(e.Message, "TestQueue_skipped"));
        });
    });

    bus.Start();

    return bus;
}

private static void LogMessageSent(TestMessage msg)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - Message \"{1}\" sent.", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), msg.Content));
}

private static Task LogMessageReceived(TestMessage msg, string queueName)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - Message \"{1}\" received on queue \"{2}\".", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), msg.Content, queueName));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public class TestMessage
{
    public string Content { get; }

    public TestMessage(string content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling `Publish`, the message is sent to every subscriber. Since each receive endpoint is adding the consumer, that creates a subscription (and subsequent exchange binding in RabbitMQ) for that message type. You can disable this by specifying `BindMessageExchanges = false` on that *skipped* receive endpoint. You will need to manually remove the exchange binding on the broker.

As to your TimeToLive question, that isn't how it works. TimeToLive is passed to the broker, and if the message expires, it is moved to a broker-specified dead-letter queue, if so configured. It is not moved to the *skipped* queue which has a different meaning in MassTransit. In MassTransit, the *skipped* queue is for messages that are delivered to a receive endpoint but there wasn't a consumer configured on that endpoint to consume the message.

For RabbitMQ, you can configure the dead-letter queue in MassTransit by using:

```
endpoint.BindDeadLetterQueue("dead-letter-queue-name");
```

This will configure the broker so that messages which reach their TTL are moved to the specified exchange/queue. Then your consumer on that receive endpoint will be able to consume them (again, be sure to set `BindMessageExchanges = false` on the dead-letter receive endpoint.

For example:

```
c.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestQueue_expired", x =>
{
    x.BindMessageExchanges = false;
    x.Handler<TestMessage>(e => LogMessageReceived(e.Message, "TestQueue_expired"));
});
```

And then your original receive endpoint:

```
c.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestQueue", x =>
{
    x.BindDeadLetterQueue("TestQueue_expired");
    x.Handler<TestMessage>(e => LogMessageReceived(e.Message, "TestQueue"));
});
```

Comment: I ran the example with the code changes you suggested, and the message was added to the "_expired" queue on timeout, but it was also added to that same queue right away, as if the "BindMessageExchanges = false" configuration was ignored. Is there any additional configuration I need to add?

Comment: As I said, you need to go into the management console for RabbitMQ and remove the binding that was already created due to your previous configuration.

Comment: I see. I thought that removing the queue would remove the exchange as well, but it was not the case. When I removed the exchange manually it worked. Thank you!